# specializing associated type inside function

Tags: scala

I have a trait that defines an associated type. In a function, I want to return this associated type which is different depending on the supplied value:

```
sealed trait Abstract {
  type T
}

class Impl1 extends Abstract {
  type T = Int
}

class Impl2 extends Abstract {
  type T = Boolean
}

object G {
  def get[A <: Abstract] (x: A): A#T = {
    x match {
      case i1: Impl1 =>
        5
      case i2: Impl2 =>
        true
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, that scala doesn't recognize that in the matched case `A#T` is `Int` or `Boolean` respectively and I get the following error message:

```
Expression of type Int doesn't conform to expected type A#T
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with such a code?

Comment: @metaphori: In my use case, I have a bunch of questions which define their result type. I then have a function `calculateResponse[Q <: Question] (q: Q): Q#Result` that produces an answer from a question (depending on additional state).

Comment: So you pattern match on the kinds of questions, don't you?

Comment: yes. In Haskell this works as the types are correctly inferred. I just wonder if this is possible in Scala too or if I should use other design patterns.
For now, I solved this by making an answer trait and just making the function `calculateResponse (q: Question): Result`. This isn't as type safe, but maybe doing  less type hackery is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, that scala doesn't recognize that in the matched case A#T is Int or Boolean respectively

Strictly speaking, it isn't. For example, you could call

```
get[Abstract](new Impl1)
```

in which case `A#T` is `Abstract#T` which is neither `Int` not `Boolean`. Or

```
get(throw new Exception)
```

so you get `Nothing#T` (`Nothing <: Abstract`, after all!).

Generally speaking, in my experience Scala isn't that good even at GADTs, and doing things like that you often have to "help" it by using casts, and it's your responsibility to make sure they are safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your `match` condition gives AnyVal result, it know nothing about `A#T`. You should use `.asInstanceOf[A#T]` on result or extrac pattern matching

```
val z = x match {
  case i1: Impl1 =>
    5
  case i2: Impl2 =>
    true
}
z match  {
  case x: A#T => x
}
```

Comment: so even if scala seems unable to check this constraint, is it save to use `asInstanceOf` in this case, i. e. does it never throw a `CastClassException` (or the `match` doesn't fail)?

Comment: in this particular case you'll not get `ClassCastException`, but in general  you should avoid such necessity of using `asInstanceOf`